# ARSSを用いたスペクトログラム の表示

Tags: python, python3, macos

[ARSS]: http://arss.sourceforge.net　という音声分析系のアプリケーションを用いて、
wavファイルからスペクトログラムに変換、表示させる方法を知りたいです。

/usr/local/Cellar/arss/0.2.3 にARSSを保存しています。
また、簡易的に実行できるコマンドラインがあるらしいのですが、調べても見つかりません。。
環境はmac mojaveです.

よろしくお願いします。

以下のwavファイルを変換させたいです。

Comment: wavfileのリンク貼り忘れです。https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PHhTY35-xCACvvc1Lm4p9bb_9eBRFWw3/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Kenza さん> 質問は編集することで質問文へ情報を追記出来るので、もしよろしければ、質問文の下にある [\[編集\]](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/59741/edit) ボタンから当該wavファイルのリンクを追記していただけませんか？